# What I can put in href in contact form?

Tags: php, html

I own a template where contact form is not done yet. template owners gave me php file a js forms file. But when I press SEND it goes nowhere. no message being sent. may be because of this?

```
<a href="#" class="button-3" data-type="submit">
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know if we don't know a single thing about the code?

Comment: I was trying to put codes here but I ended up with errors. ((

Comment: So that's not useful. Note than `<a href="#">` will navigate to an anchor `#`. So it works ok. To submit, you need a button, or a javascript that converts your `<a>` in a submit button. Try to learn HTML before coding.

Comment: No. I did not mean that I only have that line of code. I understand that anchoring something to # will bring me to nowhere. i just wanted to know may be someone can suggest what to put instead of  # ?

Comment: I have  MailHandler.php and forms.js